# how to see all images while scrolling in my layout

Tags: java, android

i'm working on an app for android,in my principal layout i have a gridlayout which contains many imageButton ,the problem is when i scroll the page to the bottom it doesn't show all my images!!

this is my actual code ,and by the way i have fixed the width and height for my images with 96px

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/alphabet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/alphabet" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/essentials"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/essentials" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/conversation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/conversation" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/numbers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/numbers" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"

            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/date" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/directions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/directions" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/transport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"

            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/transport" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/hotel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/hotel" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/restaurent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/shopping"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/shopping" />


        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/colors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/colors" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/countries"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/countries" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/family"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/family" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/dating" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/emergency" />
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and that's the result of my code:

[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ueQV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line from **GridLayout**

```
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
```

Comment: its doesnt work because when i delete that line,the first 2 images are not shown correctly,so i will get the same problem on the top of my layout

Answer (score 0):

Try to add layout_marginBottom to your **GridLayout**

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

Comment: Try to put the GridLayout inside a RelativeLayout and set Margins 50dp for the RelativeLayout